# HttpWebRequest return broken chars

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack

I'm reading a Dutch webpage :

```
HttpWebRequest oReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(website);
oReq.Method  = "GET";       
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)oReq.GetResponse();
HtmlDocument doc;
doc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

When I get the text of some random element within the page I get some weird characters not the Dutch ones I see in Chrome:

```
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
if(node != null)
{
     MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText, "--- just scrapped some xpath ---");                           
}
```

Instead of **café** I get **cafÃ©**

How do I solve this? I get the same text when writting it to a file, when I assign it to a richtextbox, etc ,etc, the same broken text.

Comment: Try changing the encoding to Unicode, e.g. utf-8

Comment: Thanks! Big code I'm working with , I tried that in another path of the code that wasn't being processed and thought I really excluded that possibility. Big thanks again! Put this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the encoding to Unicode, e.g. utf-8